# How to get average column size from stats when columns have large values

Tags: postgresql

Postgres maintains a table `pg_statistics` (and `pg_stats`), that keep track of average column size namely `stawidth` (and `avg_width` in `pg_stats`) for each column of each table in the DB.

This works fine as far as the column size is smaller than a few KB (2KB or 4KB). But for columns that are even larger size, entire data is moved to `TOAST` storage, and the table column only stores the pointer to the `TOAST`.

So the stats tables think that the content size of that column is = pointer size to `TOAST` (which in my tests came out to be 18 bytes)

As a result stats table also track this 18 bytes only, and not the full size of the column (few KBs)

In the following example table `users` has a column `name`, as has only one row with value of name to be 2KB string.
[image]

This makes average column size of `pg_statistics` table to be useless from an end user perspective, as its not showing the average of the data written by them.

Is there a way to get the actual average column size (and not the average of pointer sizes) using statistic tables ?

The dataset is large, and I cannot do runtime evaluation of the average frequently. I need some kind of prefilled stats.